# Using Scala generics: Class[T] does not take parameters

Tags: scala, generics

I have a Java application and I want to move to Scala. So I have this inner class (the original one, you can find here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab(): `public static class TabListener ...`)

```
class MyListener[T <: MySuperClass]
    (var myClass: Class[T], ...) 
    extends MyActionListener { ... }
```

My problem is, how to call this class. I tried this:

```
myObject.setMyListener(
    new MyListener[MySubClassOfMySuperClass]
    (classOf(MySubClassOfMySuperClass), ...));
```

But I get the error in my IDE (classOf(MySubClassOfMySuperClass)):

```
Class[T] does not take parameters
```

So, I have two questions:

- Is my Scala `class MyListener` defined correctly, especially `Class[T]`, because I copied this from Java code (see hyperlink of the Android API)?
- What I have to do to get the `new MyListener` working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala always uses square brackets for type parameters, so what you want to do is simply this:

```
myObject.setMyListener(new MyListener[MySubClassOfMySuperClass]
                           (classOf[MySubClassOfMySuperClass],  ...));
```

By the way, the confusing diagnostic is because `classOf`, which yields an instance of `java.lang.Class`, is not a value that can be invoked like a function or method ("does not take parameters"). Remember that Scala will always try to infer type parameters to generics such as `classOf` and oddly enough, it does so successfully when used without any type parameters. It infers the type `Nothing`:

```
scala> classOf
res1: Class[Nothing] = null
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, solved! My Java -> Scala transformation is okay so?